# Reverse SSH to remote host

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

What I need is to be able to connect reversely to Raspberry Pi that has only GSM connection.

I can send an SMS to trigger some event (for example, to run something), but not sure how it should be done.

What should I run on Raspberry (Debian 7.8, `ssh`) and on my computer (with Windows with public IP, putty) so it would connect. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to your Raspberry without public IP, you need reverse port forwarding feature of SSH and also running [sshd server](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) on the computer with public ip. Lets pretend that `pi` is your Raspberry and `pc` is your computer.

```
pi $ ssh -NTf -R 22:localhost:2222 pc
```

then you should be able to connect from your `pc` to your `pi` as

```
pc $ ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

(or similar with putty) But you might have problems with breaking SSH connections over GSM, because of really large latencies.

Comment: Any info if putty can do that all? Or I need some additional SSH server on Windows?

Comment: putty is ssh client and not server. Other possibility would be some other server with public IP, you can forward your traffic through.

Answer (score 2):

This answer isn't Pi-specific, but I'd be tempted to try this:

- Use a [dynamic dns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service to give your pi a domain name. To do this you sign up for a service (some of them are free, a choice of providers is listed on the Wikipedia page for DDNS) and then you run a small daemon on the pi that connects to the DDNS service and updates it with the new IP address whenever it changes.
- Then, `ssh` in the normal way to the domain provided by the DDNS provider. If this is part of an automated process then you'll need to consider the scenario where it fails to connect (e.g. if it fails then try again in 10 minutes)

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: I personally use CloudFlare. Their API is not for the weak, but it gives me almost instant DNS propagation. No stale problems.

Comment: @PandaLion98, thanks for the constructive edit. Staleness also depends on how frequently the ddns daemon runs on the pi though (not just DNS propagation time). Intervals measured in minutes aren't uncommon as default settings.

Comment: Do some additional coding and you'll end up with zero stale time. What I do every 1 minute is check my IP address. If it's the same, carry on. If it's different, change it.

Comment: that won't work... told you it's a GSM connection... those are behind NAT that doesn't allow you to listen on any port, so the problem is not with domain, neither IP

Comment: @FlashThunder, presumably port 80 is allowed? In /etc/ssh/sshd_config set Port to 80 and it'll listen on port 80.

Comment: @A E 11 hours ago I'm telling you, it won't. Generally IP that you get with modem is like 10.x.x.x, it's some internal network of GSM provider... the public ip is not passing any incomming connections to that local one. It's not the matter of port or nat settings - its providers network. Port 80 won't be allowed neither.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install [`tor`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en) and expose SSH via Tor hidden service. On your RPi, you will need to run `sshd` and [configure](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) `tor` as follows:

```
    HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
    HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

Note the hidden service name (which looks like "randomcharacters.onion") which you will connect to.

On your client computer you will need `tor` running as well. You will also need to make sure SSH will use `tor` while connecting, e.g.

```
torify ssh user@randomcharacters.onion
```